# Error: Cannot convert value of type 'B' to expected argument type 'A<Any>' where B is a child of A

Tags: ios, swift, oop

I get the following error when calling a function `reloadTableView(dataSource: matchedSchoolProgramDataSource)`

```
 Cannot convert value of type 'MatchedSchoolProgramDataSource'
 to expected argument type 'DataSource<Any>'
```

Where DataSource is a generic `class DataSource<T>` and `MatchedSchoolProgramDataSource: DataSource<Int>` and reloadTableview is function in a protocol.

```
protocol TableViewResponseDelegate{

    func reloadTableView(dataSource: DataSource<Any>)
}
```

The reason for doing this: I have multiple table view controllers whose cells are filled by response from different network calls. I want to use **one** delegate that reloads tableview when it receives a response from the network. Datasource is a generic parent class of all data sources of tableview controllers.

Comment: That's not quite how generics work. `DataSource<Any>` is a different Type from `DataSource<Int>`.

Comment: Because there can be different types of DataSources, I do not want to use reloadTableView(dataSource: DataSource<Int>) in my protocol. How can make my protocol generic so that it can be used by different datasources?

Comment: I don't really know what you're trying to do, but would it work to do `func reloadTableView<T>(dataSource: DataSource<T>)`?

Comment: How would I write a implement a func whoes protocol func is one you gave?

Comment: Also, swift only allows associated types in protocols.

Comment: again...I don't know what you're trying to do. Post how you want to use it and what you're trying to accomplish rather than "this doesn't work".

Comment: @PEEJWEEJ Thanks for your reply. I updated the question with the reason.